# Having issues using Pick utility type with React useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand why can't I use `Pick` utility type to pick one property from my interface and use it to type my component's state.

Here's the interface:

```
export interface IBooking {
  ...
  propertyId: string | null;
  ...
}
```

And then in my component I have the following:

```
const [propertyId, setPropertyId] = useState<Pick<IBooking, 'propertyId'>>('some-id');
```

This is the error I get:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick  | (() => Pick )'.
```

However, if I just replace `Pick<IBooking, 'propertyId'>` with `string | null`, it, of course, works. And I don't understand what is the difference. Isn't it exactly what `Pick` type should do? I didn't have much experience with utility types, but I'm using `Pick` type perfectly fine in another place. Is it because some specifics of `useState` hook?

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `propertyId` on `IBooking` is of the type `string | null` then it will be the following type:

```
{
    propertyId: string | null;
}
```

The result of Pick is an object containing only attributes which are listed.

You can use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) like this instead:

`IBooking["propertyId"]`

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. One more question... Is there a way to quickly see what my "type" returns? I mean if I could see that Pick returns an object, I would not ask this question. Or should I just know it? Anyway, big thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I am not aware of such a feature, and it seems that the TypeScript docs just use this type with an actual value to see if it gets rejected. In some IDEs though, you can hover over the `"propertyId"` part of `IBooking["propertyId"]` and it will tell you the underlying type. But that's all I am aware of.